# How to make my Mac screen a mirror of iPhone using AirPlay

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, cocoa, airplay

I'm new to AirPlay.  I want to find a good tutorial to learn about Airplay and its APIs and how I can use it for sharing my iPhone screen on my Mac device.

What I learned:

1. iPhone 4S+ will support AirPlay, but how can I make my Mac capture the screen of iPhone?
2. RTSP and RTP Protocols are used. Do we have to implement it in our code?

In the link http://spin.atomicobject.com/2012/04/23/ios-mirroring-and-programmatic-airplay-selection/
I didn't get what author meant by

> What developers cannot do:
>   i. Allow users to enable mirroring within an application.
>   ii. Programmatically select remote screens or provide an alternative selection method outside of MPVolumeView.

Please help me to learn more about it.

Comment: "(I didn't get what author mean by) What developers cannot do: i. Allow users to enable mirroring within an application." - that's exactly what you are trying to do. Gotta roll your own implementation.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, But there are some application which can do that.. can i get rough idea how they are doing that?

Comment: "gotta roll your own implementation"...

Comment: can u suggest me some good tutorial to learn about airPlay and its API's?

Answer (score -1):

I use third party app, calls [X-Mirrage](http://www.x-mirage.com)

, It's very sample AirPlay way

Comment: Please expand your answer... If the link goes dead, what should we know about X-Mirrage or anything else?